# What is this C++ technique for adding types to a class called?

Tags: c++, derived-types

I've just found some C++ code (at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8336763(VS.71).aspx), which uses a technique I've never seen before to add types to an existing class:

```
class Testpm {
public:
   void m_func1() { cout << "m_func1\n"; }
   int m_num;
};

// Define derived types pmfn and pmd.
// These types are pointers to members m_func1() and m_num, respectively.
void (Testpm::*pmfn)() = &Testpm::m_func1;
int Testpm::*pmd = &Testpm::m_num;

int main() {
   Testpm ATestpm;
   Testpm *pTestpm = new Testpm;

   // Access the member function
   (ATestpm.*pmfn)();
   (pTestpm->*pmfn)();   // Parentheses required since * binds

   // Access the member data
   ATestpm.*pmd = 1;
   pTestpm->*pmd = 2;

   cout  << ATestpm.*pmd << endl
         << pTestpm->*pmd << endl;
}
```

Can someone please tell me what this technique for defining derived types is called, or point me to some documentation on it? I've never come across it in 13 years of using C++, and would like to end my ignorance.

Comment: What do you mean by "add types to an existing class"? Also, can you point out what part of the code "adds types to an existing class"? All I see is the use of pointers to members.

Comment: I refer you to the comment

    // Define derived types pmfn and pmd.

and lines such as 

    ATestpm.*pmd = 1;

which suggest that 'pmd' has been added to the class Testpm. These are what prompted my question, and the way I worded it.

Looking at the code now, and with the benefit of the answers provided so far, I can see that pmd and pmfn are being defined as pointers to members inside Testpm. It's the fact that they're pointers into a class rather than an object, and the way they can be accessed from Testpm objects, that's confusing me, as I don't recall ever seeing this before.

Comment: They are pointers to members of the class. 'pmfn': Is a pointer to a member function and 'pmd': Is a pointer to member data. These concepts are used heavily within the algorithms of the STL though this is not exposed to the user of the STL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comment is incorrect: pmfn and pmd are not "derived types" at all (they are not even types!). They are [pointers to members](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=142).

Comment: hard to believe, but true: even pointers to members are types.

Comment: "Are types", or "have types"? If I wrote typedef int Testpm::*pmd_t = &Testpm::m_num; pmd_t pmd; clearly pmd_t is a type, but do you mean pmd is a type also? The second case applies to the code in the question.

Comment: Looks like they put `typedef`, and then removed it and forgot to change the comment. In fact, what is called "compound type" in C++ is called "derived type" in C, thus the comment in the code, i believe.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think they're "adding types" to the class.  They seem to be just defining types of pointers to member functions and member data of the class, and then using those to access the member function and data member.  Similar to how you'd declare types to non-member functions, but being members of the class the syntax differs.

From this site [here](http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html)

> Regarding their syntax, there are two
>   different types of function pointers:
>   On the one hand there are pointers to
>   ordinary C functions or to static C++
>   member functions. On the other hand
>   there are pointers to non-static C++
>   member functions. The basic difference
>   is that all pointers to non-static
>   member functions need a hidden
>   argument: The this-pointer to an
>   instance of the class. Always keep in
>   mind: These two types of function
>   pointers are incompatible with each
>   other.

Comment: In fact they're not even defining types of pointers - they're defining the pointers themselves.

Comment: I stand corrected, they're not defining types to the pointers, just creating instances of them and using them. I blame a lack of sleep...